# Connecting MacBook Air external display without using onboard display

Tags: display

My MacBook Air display crushed but rest is ok. The apple authority advised to change the display, but I would like to use external display option. Since the onboard display is gone, is there any way to connect up external display like plug and play sort of thing?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, all monitors are plug and play, just plug an hdmi cable into the air and the monitor.